# Best way to switch wrapping elements using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this code in HTML

```
<span id="s">Attachments</span>
```

How to use jQuery to switch the outer SPAN element with the following table code block, so that the "Attachments" text becomes wrapped with the table element.

```
<table id="t">
  <tr>
    <td>Attachments</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Found a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872320/jquery-changing-wrapping-tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a table with a tr and td, insert the HTML contents from the span into that new td element, insert the table immediately after the span, and then finally, remove the span.

```
$("<table id='t'><tr><td>" + $("#s").html() +
    "</td></tr></table").insertAfter("#s");

$("#s").remove();
```

I'm assuming by "swipe" you mean "swap"?  So that's why I've removed the original span. If this is not the case, just leave out the `remove` call.

Comment: Try this instead: http://jsfiddle.net/Fh24j/. I had to change the jsFiddle to not use onLoad as it wasn't able to define your function. I also simplified the code and put insertAfter on the same command that creates the table.

Comment: Removing my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the `#s` element, then replace it with its own contents:

```
$("#s")
  .wrap("<table id='t'><tr><td></td></tr></table>")
  .replaceWith(function(){ 
      return this.innerHTML; 
  });
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/elotan/edit#source

Following further discussion in the comments below, it appears the OP wanted to be able to create a table ad-hoc, and insert `#s` into any of its `td`'s. The following may be better:

```
$("<table>", { 
  id:'t', html:'<tr><td>Foo</td><td>' + $("#s").html() + '</td></tr>'
}).replaceAll("#s");
```

Comment: This is great! I am a little puzelled how does it know where to insert the text. For example:http://jsbin.com/asinop 
How dose it know to insert the "Attachement" in Cell-1, but not in cell-2?

Comment: @RegisteredUser The first cell is considered the first inner-most container. As such, it is the eventual location used. I would avoid getting too complicated with your wrapper-string though.

Comment: OK, but just a question. What if I want the location to be the second TR/TD as a container? What modification should I do?

Comment: @RegisteredUser That's an entirely different question my friend :) However, I would suggest you create the new table, then assign the unwrapped text of `#s` as the value of the second `tr`/`td`.

Comment: Well the question was simplified to reduce complexity. My actual need is to insert it into a more complex table. I will have to give the correct answer to @jmort253 as his solution is more flexible.

Comment: @RegisteredUser Even though I feel two distinct problems are being solved, I have updated my answer per our discussion here.