# How to change the wrapping tag in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The following line of code, will change a `p` tag to a `div` tag:

```
$('p').contents().unwrap().wrap('<div />');
```

**Here is the issue:**

This will also turn any inner tags into `div`s as well!

Example:

Take the following HTML:

```
<p>abc<a>121</a>cba</p>
```

Running my code above gives me this:

```
<div>abc</div>
<div><a>121</a></div>
<div>cba</div>
```

But I would like to achieve this:

```
<div>abc<a>121</a>cba</div>
```

What can I do to achieve this, and why does it work when mine does not?

Comment: This is really ugly DOM manipulation; if you need to do something like this to make some code do something then there's probably something wrong at a higher level. This should do it: $('p').unwrap().wrap('<div />');

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need

```
$('p').wrap('<div />').contents().unwrap();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vmJ4v/)

Your code is wrong because

1. `$('p').contents().unwrap()` will remove the `p` element and add all the child nodes to the parent of `p` element, then the set has 3 elements.
2. `.wrap('<div />');` will wrap all the three elements with `div` tag

Another possible solution is

```
$('p').contents().unwrap().wrapAll('<div />');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vmJ4v/2/)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$('p').replaceWith($('<div>'+ $('p').html()+ '</div>'));
```